# Syscall print int

Tags: mips

I am just wondering why this doesn't work:

```
Print Integer:   li $v0, 1
             li, $a0, $v0     #with $v0 being an added up value
             syscall
```

But, this works:

```
Print Integer:  li $v0, 1
        li, $a0, 100
        syscall
```

Is there any register that I can use to print an integer that has been altered by an algorithm? I always thought $v0 was the register that stores returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you've got a syntax error here:

```
li, $a0, $v0
```

There should be no comma after `li`.

Secondly, the purpose of the `li` pseudo-instruction is to load *immediates* (e.g. 1, 0x42, or 12345). If you want to move (copy) the contents of one register to another, use `move` (as in `move $a0, $v0`).

And finally, you assigned `$v0` the value 1 on the first line of your code, so even if you correctly said `move $a0, $v0` you'd always get `$a0 = 1`. If you want the previous value of `$v0` you have to do `move $a0, $v0` before `li $v0, 1`.

Comment: The comma was just an error when I pasted it here, and thanks, what I ended up doing was moving the answer to $s0 and putting that above the `li $v0, 1` like you said.